# Pull a string out of a string (split?)

Tags: python

I have a string - a sample would be the below:

```
g0/1                  192.168.1.1     YES NVRAM  up                    up
```

I want to pull the IP address out of it but not the last octet. I want to pull 192.168.1. out of it so it can used later.

I think I need to use split, but am not sure on how to achieve this.

```
output = '    g0/1                  192.168.1.1     YES NVRAM  up                    up'
ouput = ouput.split('192.168.1.',)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply use `split()`.

```
>>> output.split()[1].rsplit(".", 1)[0]
'192.168.1'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Regular Expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

```
import re

input_string = "g0/1                  192.168.1.1     YES NVRAM  up                    up"
output = re.search('\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.', input_string)
```

EDIT: Changed from `match()` to `search()` since `match()` only looks at the beginning of the string.

Also, assuming you want to do this for more than one string, you can use the [`findall()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) function, instead, which will return a list of all the matching groups of your regular expression.

```
> import re

> input_string = "g0/1                  192.168.1.1     YES NVRAM  up                    up"
> outputs = re.search('\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.', input_string)
> print(outputs)
['192.168.1.']
```

Comment: I would humbly suggest that regular expressions is far too heavy a hammer for this task.

Comment: True. I seem to have fallen into the trap of using RegExes even when not necessary.